# Inserting index.phtml view from side controller in the main index.phtml

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have Entry controller with index action that lists all entries, and of course views/scripts/index.phtml. I also have the main page index/index.phtml. How can I include entry/index.phtml in index/index.phtml so I can see the results of entries as part of the structure of the home page?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this towards the end of your indexAction() in the index controller:

```
$this->_helper->actionStack('index', 'entry');
```

Alternatively, I think you may be able to to do think in the index/index.phtml script:

```
<?php echo $this->action('index', 'entry');?>
```

First example is the [actionStack action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.actionstack) the second is the [action view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action)

Good luck!

Comment: You should avoid `actionStack` because [actionStack is evil](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

You may create view helper for this, in which you:

- retrieve the data (e.g. from database)
- pass the data to the view
- render the view you need (`$this->view->render('pathoto/scriptname.phtml')`). You may also add script path using `addScriptPath()`.

Then use this helper in those two scripts you need.

If AJAX it the root of your needs, take a look at `actionContext` and `ajaxContext` action helpers.

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html